# В Андроид приложении заполнить массив данными из текстового файла

Tags: java, android, android-studio, файлы

> Ошибка:W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.terminator.wordgame/files/marki_avto: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).

Можно ли как-то файл перенести в нужную директорию? Как еще можно выкрутиться?Количество записей в документе известно заранее.

```
  //final String FILENAME = "marki_avto";
  try 
  {
       BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( openFileInput(FILENAME)));
       for(int i=0; i<auto_array.length;i++)
       {
           auto_array[i]=reader1.readLine();
       }
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Да можно. Открываете 2 проводника, в одном папка где есть файл, во втором куда надо перенести и перетаскиваете мышкой. Пишите больше информации, хотите ли программно перенести? Знаете ли начальное расположение файла или он приходит откуда-то?

Comment: Так файл перенести в нужную директорию или заполнить массив данными из файла?

Comment: А где у Вас этот файл сейчас? Вы записали его туда, откуда пытаетесь прочитать?

Comment: файл сейчас в папке java в андройдовском проекте. А переносить не программно

Comment: Используйте Files.copy или Files.move. Просто, чтобы удовлетворить интерес - почему не открыть его там где он есть?

Comment: Если не планируется изменение этого файла во время работы приложения, то будет удобнее оформить его в виде [StringArray](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) (пример там есть) .Если же Вы будете показывать ещё кучу связанной информации (подробные характеристики авто, например) - то лучше смотреть в сторону базы данных.